# ksqldb cli failed to teminate a query:Timeout while waiting for command topic consumer to process command topic

Tags: ksqldb

I want to terminate a query to drop a table. But i got the below error, and after while the query is terminated, the ksql log don't print any error message. How can i find the root cause?

ksql> terminate CTAS_KSQL1_TABLE_SACMES_PACK_STATS_275;
Could not write the statement 'terminate CTAS_KSQL1_TABLE_SACMES_PACK_STATS_275;' into the command topic.
Caused by: Timeout while waiting for command topic consumer to process command topic

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may have run into a bug in older versions of ksqlDB. Maybe this one: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/4267

The general issue is that the query gets into a state where it can't close down cleanly. What's blocking the shutdown does eventually complete or timeout. In the case of issue #4267 above, the issue was that the sink topic, i.e. the topic ksqlDB is writing to, has been deleted out-of-band, i.e. by something other than ksqlDB, and ksqlDB is stuck trying to get metadata for a non-existent topic.  Did you delete the sink topic?

There were others resolved issues too that I can't find.

Bouncing the server after issuing the terminate should clean up the stuck query. Though it's a pretty severe workaround!

Upgrading to a later version, something released after May 2020, the issue should be resolved.

Comment: Hi Andrew Coates, the ksqldb's version is 0.11.0. I install two ksqldb in the same machine, and use the same kafka cluster. I am not sure if that's the reason.

Comment: Hi Jun, two instances on the same machine shouldn't cause any issues. They'll just cluster together if configured right.

If this is happening on 0.11, then I'd urge you to raise a [bug in Github](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug%2C+needs-triage&template=bug_report.md&title=) with details.  If you can work out steps to reliably recreate then its much more likely someone will be able to get to the bottom of your issue.